# Fetching and Displaying User's details

Tags: javascript, arrays, fetch-api

1. Within `fetchAndDisplayUsers`, after the call to `displayUsers`, declare an API variable and set it value to https://randomapi.com/api/y1lfp11q?key=LEIX-GF3O-AG7I-6J84
2. Use the Browser's fetch API to make a HTTP call to the API endpoint represented by API
3. The fetch call returns a Promise, that contains the response. Use an arrow function in a `.then` call to convert the response to JSON.
4. Use an arrow function in another .then call to receive the converted JSON data. The arrow function should de-structure its parameter to get the results property. The function body should then de-structure results (an array) to get the first item (the user object from the API), which should be assigned to a user variable. Finally, it should add the user object to our users array and then call `displayUsers` with an inline array containing the new user object.
5. Add error handling to the fetch call.

I want this function to fetch data from the API and display them.

```
const fetchAndDisplayUsers = () => {
        users.push({
          age: 40,
          weight: 75,
          height: 6,
          country: 'Nigeria',
          name: 'Charles Odili',
          id: 'dfhb454768DghtF'
        });
        
        users.push({
          age: 26,
          weight: 72,
          height: 6,
          country: 'Ugandan',
          name: 'Peter Odili',
          id: 'gydf4'
        });
        
        displayUsers(users);
            const api =  'https://randomapi.com/api/y1lfp11q?key=LEIX-GF3O-AG7I-6J84'
              fetch(api)
               .then(response => {
                     return response.json();
               })  
               .then(({results}) => {
                users = users.concat(results);
                displayUsers(users);
              }).catch(error => {
                 console.log(error);
              })

        const displayUsers = (results) => {
           const selectItems = document.querySelector('.select-text');
            users.forEach(element => {
                console.log(element);
                const options = document.createElement("option");
                options.textContent = element.name;
                options.value = element.id;
                selectItems.appendChild(options);
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const api =  'https://randomapi.com/api/y1lfp11q?key=LEIX-GF3O-AG7I-6J84'
fetch(api)
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })  
  .then(({results}) => {
    const [ user ] = results;
    users.push(user);
    displayUsers(users);
  })
  .catch(error => { console.log(error)})
```